# What is the story of Omkareshwar Jyotirlinga?

Tags: shiva, scripture, temple, shiva-lingam, jyotirlinga

Lord Shiva has been worshipped in Linga form from time beginning as described in [answer here.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/101/why-is-shiva-primarily-worshipped-in-a-linga-form/14214#14214) Among the Lingas there are 12 Jyotirlingas which are of special importance.

Mahatmya of 12 Jyotirlingas is described in Koti Rudra Samhita of Shiva Purana in the chapter "Dwadash Jyotirlinga Mahatmya". It states:

> सौराष्ट्रे सोमनाथं च श्री शैले मल्लिकार्जुनम् ।
> उज्जयिन्यां महाकाल**मोंकारे** परमेश्वरम् ।।
> केदारं हिमवत्पृष्ठे डाकिन्यां भीमशङ्करम् ।
> वाराणास्यां च विश्वेशं त्रयम्बकं गौतमीतटे ।।
> वैद्यनाथं चिताभूमौ नागेशं दारुकावने ।
> सेतुबन्धे तु रामेशं घुश्मेशं च शिवालये ।।
> **द्वादशैतानि नामानि प्रात्यस्त्थाय यः पठेत् ।
>
> सर्वपापविनिर्मुक्तं सर्वसिद्धिफलं लभेत्** ।।
>  
> Somanath in Saurashtra, Mallikarjuna in Shri Saile, Mahakala in Ujjaiyana and Parameshawara also manifested as Omkara. Kedara in Himavat and Bhima Shankara in Dakinya. Vishewaswara in Varanasi and Trayambaka in side of Gautami. Vaidyanath in ChitaBhumi and  Nageshwara in forest of Daruka. Rameshwara in Setubandha and Ghusmeshwara in Shivalaya. **These name of 12 Jyotirlingas who recites in morning, he gets freed from all sins and is eligible to get all Siddhis.**

There are twelve [Jyotirlingas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jyotirlinga#Sanskrit_Sloka) mentioned in the similar popular verse.

> Saurāṣṭre Somanāthaṃ ca Śrīśaile Mallikārjunam
>
> Ujjayinyāṃ Mahākālam **Omkāram** Mamleśhwaram
>
> Paraly Vaidyanāthaṃ cha Ḍākinyāṃ Bhīmaśhaṅkaram
>
> Setubandhe tu Rāmeśaṃ Nāgeśhaṃ Dārukāvane
>
> Vārāṇasyāṃ tu Viśveśaṃ Tryambakaṃ Gautamītaṭe
>
> Himālaye tu Kedāraṃ Ghuśmeśaṃ ca Śivālaye
>
> etāni jyotirliṅgāni sāyaṃ prātaḥ paṭhennaraḥ
>
> saptajanmakṛtaṃ pāpaṃ smaraṇena vinaśyati

I have already asked a question about Somanath [What is the story of Somanath Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14213/what-is-the-story-of-somanath-jyotirlinga) and Mallikarjun [What is the story of Mallikarjuna Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14223/what-is-the-story-of-mallikarjuna-jyotirlinga) and Mahakaleshwar [What is the story of Mahakaleshwar Jyotirlinga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14243/what-is-the-story-of-mahakaleshwar-jyotirlinga). Now I want to know the story of **Omkareshwar** Jyotirling.

Please mention the scriptural reference.

Omkareshwar temple is situated in [Khandwa, Madhya Pradesh](https://www.google.com/maps/place/22%C2%B014%2744.1%22N+76%C2%B009%2703.8%22E/@22.245583,76.151056,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d22.245583!4d76.151056?hl=en).

[image]

By Bernard Gagnon - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=31736612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your yesterday's suggestion into account, the answer is posted short. The story about Mahakaleswara told in the Koti Rudra Samhita of Siva Maha Purana taken from [here](https://archive.org/details/SivaPuranaJ.L.ShastriPart3). The below is passage is taken from Kanchi Kamakoti Website in which the essence of different puranas is listed. The link for Jyotirlingas is [here](http://kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/shivapuranam22.html).

> Situated in the banks of River Narmada on the Mandhata (Shivapuri)
> Island formed in the shape of OM in Sanskrit, Omkareswar is one of the
> Jyotirlingas besides another Amareswar Linga. The Legend was that Sage
> Narada visited Vindhya Raja and the latter bragged that Vindya was the
> highest and most powerful Mountain in the entire World. Narada replied
> that perhaps Meru was the greatest in terms of height and might.
> Vindhya Raja felt jealous and executed severe ‘Tapasya’ and pleased
> Maha Siva and requested that He should always be present in the
> Vindhyas and establish a Linga of Bhagavan on the banks of Narmada
> near to Vindhya. Hence the Omkara Jyotirlinga there. Puffed by Siva’s
> presence there, Vindhya Raja grew taller and taller to compete with
> Sumeru. This obstructed Sun God’s routine circumambulation of the
> Universe and He had to return half way turning half of the Universe
> dark. Bhagavati asked Sage Agastya from Kasi to visit Vindhya Raja who
> out of veneration bent down to touch the feet of Agastya who asked
> Vindhya to be in that position till he returned and he never came
> again from the South!

Hope this helps you.