# Which Scriptures say Shiva is easily pleased than rest of Gods?

Tags: scripture, shiva, belief

It is said Shiva is easily pleased as is also His name- "AshuTosha" or "Quickly (Aashu) Satisfied (Tosha)".

**But which Scriptures specifically mention that He is the easiest to please or easily pleased than rest of Gods**. Such lines are there in each Purana of other Gods too saying that the particular deity of Puraana is easily pleased. So why is it said ***'Shiva is easiest to please than others and rest of Gods'.***

Comment: Most probably Shiva Purana.

Comment: [This answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16108/277) convers the point why is Shiva called Bholenath.

Comment: @Pandya there is no mention of word BholeNath in any Scriptures, and answer given by Tezz. Even Tezz just drew a conclusion from some incidents that seem to point towards Shiva being innocent.

Comment: One clarification here, don't you think, you should compare Lord Shiva only with Trinity like sage Brighu did to find out who is superior among Trinity. Comparing Lord Shiva with rest of Gods is like comparing human beings with Gods. Just remember the fact that "14 Indra changes in one day of the Trinity", should we compare Trinity with them?

Comment: @YDS how came you to conclusion "Comparing Shiva with rest Gods is like comparing with humans". You think only and only Trinity is supreme. No. Shiva, Vishnu, Brahma, Durga, Lakshmi, Saraswati, Ganesha, Surya and others too are as equally said to be ParaBrahma as is Shiva said supreme.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Agree, then atleast mention Aadi Devas (Trinity, Aadishakti, Ganesha, Surya).

Comment: @YDS the point of question is not at all whether who is AdiDevas, who is supreme, whom to compare with whom, who is inferior et cetera. The question is only about whether or not any Scriptures say if Shiva is easiest to please than rest of God, now be the God Trinity, NavaGrahas, Trishaktis, Maruts, Vasus et cetera. If you want, you can add a separate question whom should we compare with whom.

Comment: Bhagavta Purana

Comment: @TheDestroyer kindly provide an answer for Shiva being AshuToshi, as Ashu Toshi itself mean "easily pleased". Also, if you get other verses of benevolence of Shiva.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Which Scriptures say Shiva is easily pleased than rest of Gods in Trinity?**

> [Part 10 of Bhagavata Purana](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/88) and [Part 5 of Vishnu Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vishnu_purana/release_of_shiva_from_crisis.html)

Lord Brahma, Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva can each bestow or withhold favors, but whereas Lord Brahma and Lord Shiva are satisfied or angered very quickly (specially Lord Shiva), Lord Vishnu is not.

In this regard the Pauranik literature relates the following account:

> A snap from 88th Chapter (Release of Lord Shiva from crisis) of part 10 of Bhagavata Purana:

[image: Why Shiva is Ashutosh]

Translation in English : **Once the demon Vrakasura asked Narada which god was most quickly pleased, and Narada answered that Lord Shiva was.**

**2. Why is it said that other Gods are easy to please (specially Shiva) and not Vishnu?**

Lord Krishna had said in Bhagavata Purana:

"O Yudhisthira, I take away all the wealth from those whom I bestow my grace. When they are poor, their relatives desert them. I even render their efforts useless when they try to earn money. Thus being unsuccessful repeatedly, the people develop an attitude of indifference for wealth. Then they begin to take shelter as my devotee and mingle with me. Only then, I bestow my full grace on them and they receive me as Sachchidanand Parabrahma. **Thus, pleasing me through my worship is extremely difficult**.

> Hence, ordinary people give me up and worship other deities, which are in fact different forms of me.

Lord Shiva is **Ashutosh** and bestows his devotees quickly with grace. He gives wealth and other riches to his devotees. But once they get wealth, the devotees become despotic and even forget the God who had blessed them."

**3. Such lines are there in each Purana of other Gods too**

Yes, because most of the Puranas tell the conversation between two sages.

> So, it depends on the faith, devotion and belief of a sage who tells the story.

For instance, take these lines from Ramcharitmanas by Goswami Tulasidasji:

> जो संपति सिव रावनहि दीन्हि दिएँ दस माथ।
>   सोइ संपदा बिभीषनहि सकुचि दीन्ह रघुनाथ।।

Translation in English: This wealth was granted by Lord Shiva to Ravana after Ravana offered in sacrifice his own ten heads (i.e. had committed to serve Lord Shiva with all five sense organs and five organs of actions as preferred deity) and the same belonged to Vibhishana now which Raghunatha Shri Rama handed him with slight hesitation that it is not a sufficient reward for the divine virtues possessed by Vibhishana.

Comment: I am sorry to say. But your given answer just seem to attempt to assert that Shiva is easily pleased than others, whereas, there is no clear answer or reference that Shiva is easily pleased than rest of Gods, **as has become a common belief amongst people**.

Comment: @AnuragSingh In last part of my answer, have mentioned clearly that it depends on belief. Last doha states that Lord Shri Rama can be pleased more easily than Lord Shiva. Adding it's explanation in english.

Comment: But the last part of your answer is an conclusion made by you yourself that it depends on belief. Where is the Scriptural quotation for it?

Comment: Yes it is true that **Shiva is AshuToshi**, but kindly read question, it asks- where is it said that *Shiva is easiest to pleased **than rest of the gods**.* This has become the most common belief in India, so where is its Scriptural Reference.

Comment: @AnuragSingh please check my answer, added a snap and proper reference. Answer states that Lord Shiva can be pleased easily among Trinity. And by the way if you are talking about Lord Shiva then don't u think u should compare him only with Trinity.

Comment: I suggest you to Specify in your answer that your answer says Shiva is easiest to be pleased amongst Trinity giving quotation to conversation between Naarada and Vrikaasura.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Specified Trinity in my answer. I suggest u to edit ur question too, comparing Lord Shiva with rest of Gods is like comparing human beings with Gods. Just remember the fact that "14 Indra changes in one day of the Trinity", should we compare Trinity with them?

Comment: Which scripture mentions the concept of Ashutosh firstly?